# set netplan to use TWO static addresses preference with DHCP fallback

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I am setting up a Ubuntu 22.04 server at home for use on-site. Server needs to have a static address on-site. How to test with static address at home, then take pc to site without having to change the netplan yaml file.
Server MAY also need to use DHCP as a fallback on-site
It seems to use DHCP to get an address **in preference** to the static addresses!
I want it to use the available static addresses first!
The on-site network has two static addressed machines (MS windows 10), running a priority application, which MUST be able to connect to the server. But there are potentially other devices on the network as well.
**Does the order of netplan yaml lines influence netplan?**

My netplan file is working ok, is as below

Thanks for help!

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true
      addresses: [192.168.86.100/24, 192.168.0.199/24]
      routes:
        -to:  192.168.0.199
         via: 192.168.0.1
        -to:  192.168.86.100
         via: 192.168.86.1
      nameservers:
        search:
          - mysite.com
          - google.com
        addresses: 
          - 192.168.0.1
          - 192.168.86.1
          - 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: The description suggests that you don't actually know if the final environment is static or dhcp. Rather than create a complex and brittle solution to handle all possibilities, you could just ask the network admin. Then set up your home LAN (or subnet) to match.

Comment: Fair points, I have edited the question to includ distro is Unbuntu server 22.04, and clarified the information and question